# Error while accessing an Object containing html values in a ReactJS Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created an object whose values contain HTML, when I am accessing it, I am getting the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'AnimatedImagesConfig'

Here's my code:

```
  interface AnimatedImagesConfig {
    waterAndFire?: JSX.Element
    hasFaults?: JSX.Element
  }
  const animatedImages: AnimatedImagesConfig = {
    waterAndFire: <div className="imagesContainer frame"></div>,
    hasFaults: (
      <div className="imagesContainer">
        
      </div>
    ),
  }

const AnimatedDefault: string = animatedImages[get(wf1, 'fetchAnimationData.type')]
  let AnimatedComponent: JSX.Element | string = get(wf1, 'fetchAnimationData.hasAnimations', false) ? AnimatedDefault : <></>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, so I'd appreciate any help in this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, the keys of an object can only be strings or number same work for typescript

```
export interface Config {
  // here you can use any string type 
  [key: string]: JSX.Element;
  // here you can use key as a number
  [key: number]: JSX.Element;
}
```

Now let's see your object have interface Config

```
const object: Config = {
  // here editComponent, addComponent is object key
  editComponent: <div className="">.....</div>,
  addComponent: <div className="">.....</div>
}
```

take string type and use it as an index key

```
const type: string = 'addComponent'
```

then you can access indexing on object "Object"

```
 const keyComponent: JSX.Element = condition ? object[type] : <></>
 // or
 const editComponent: React.Component = object['editComponent']
```

use object key-value pair where the key is accepting type and value is the return type